# ExtJS form access from inside

Tags: extjs

**ExtJS 4.1**

I have `Ext.Form.Panel` and `Ext.Button` inside of it bound to form with `formBind: true;`. Is there a way to access form with button bond to it from within button's handler like `getForm()` or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query up through the button.

```
{
    xtype:'button',
    handler: function (button, e) {
        button.up('form').getForm();
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably it is the best way for now. Thanks for answer.